# function current-date xslt not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use the current-date function in xslt, but it is not working. May I miss something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
        xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        extension-element-prefixes="date" date:doc="http://www.exslt.org/date">

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
          <xsl:template match="/">
              <value><xsl:value-of select="current-date()"/></value>
          </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got an error:Error al comprobar el tipo de la expresión 'funcall(current-date, [])'.', it means "error when check the expresion 'funcall(current-date)'"

why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you perhaps tried the following (from XSLT1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
        xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        extension-element-prefixes="date" date:doc="http://www.exslt.org/date">

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
          <xsl:template match="/">
              <value><xsl:value-of select="date:date()"/></value>
          </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It returns the date only (with time zone)

Answer (score 1):

`current-date` is a XSLT 2.0 function.

But since your are using [EXSLT](http://exslt.org/date/functions/date/index.html), a call `date:date()` will return the current-date:

```
<value><xsl:value-of select="date:date()"/></value>
```